# How do I take care of valuables on a Germany trip?

Tags: luggage, germany, international-travel, security

I'm traveling to Germany in the summer for a month and will be staying in hostels (as of now). I'll be having a backpack with essentials and a small briefcase with my laptop and important documents. How do I make sure everything is safe?

Comment: Making sure "everything is safe" is a very large topic--too large to be addressed in a single answer here. Safety on trains, airplanes, in a hotel, on the street, in taxis, etc, are all varied.  You might try focusing your question somewhat.

Comment: A good general resource on physical safety while traveling, which goes into far more detail than is possible on an answer here, is the book [Travel Advisory: How to Avoid Thefts, Cons, and Street Scams](http://amzn.to/14F4xMG).

Comment: Germany is rather safe. The real criminals to watch out for when backpacking are the hostels who charge you 10 Euros/day for internet.

Answer (score 1):

We did essentially this same thing last spring. I used a passport holder that hung around my neck but under my clothes to hold my passport and any travel docs. other than exactly what I needed just then, also my emergency credit card. I never carried much cash at a time, preferring the international VISA debit card I got at my bank before going. The hostels I stayed at each had small lockers which my backpack fit into quite nicely, so I locked things up there during the day while I was out and about. I carried with me only a small messenger bag that held my tablet - left the larger laptop at home. Germany is a fairly safe country, that helps. Take good precautions and all should be well.